# Visio VBA, need to loop all pages to extract one specific shape data

Tags: vba, loops, visio

Good Day,
I'm trying to get a specific shape data from all pages in the active document.
Can someone help me with the following code?

```
Sub Macro3()

Dim Pg As Visio.Page
Dim shp As Shape

For Each Pg In Application.ActiveDocument.Pages
 shp = Pg.Shapes("Cartouche Site").CellsU("Prop.T2").formula
 Debug.Print shp.CellsU("Prop.T2").formula
Next

End Sub
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please explain better where you got stuck or have errors. Reading [ask] and [repro] should help you to improve your question. Reading [it's not working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) might also help.

Comment: The code looks like it will loop through all pages and get the Prop.T2 formula for the Cartouch Site shape on each page. Is there any particular problem with the code for which you'd like help?

Comment: Yes i want to display a list of all Prop.T2 values and it doesnt.

Comment: For example, if i have 8 pages, i want a list of 8 different Prop.T2 value.

Answer (score 0):

Marc!
Please try this modified code

```
Sub Macro3()

Dim Pg As Visio.Page
Dim shp As Shape

For Each Pg In Application.ActiveDocument.Pages
   Set shp = Pg.Shapes("Cartouche Site")
   Debug.Print shp.CellsU("Prop.T2").formula
Next

End Sub
```

Are you sure that each page contain shape named *Cartouche Site*